# How do you access the bit mysql data type in ruby on rails 2?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a field of type [`bit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-type.html) in a MySQL database, but I'm not sure how to access the value.

The ruby `debug` method gives me (note the spaces, they are probably invisible characters stored in binary form):

```
--- &id001 !ruby/object:Room 
attributes: 
  bit_field_false: !binary |
    AA==

  bit_field_true: !binary |
    AQ==
```

`bit_field_false` and `bit_field_true` should be `false` and `true` respectively. I've also noticed some weird properties:

- When I convert them to integers, they both show as `0`
- When I extract truth values, ie, `<%= @room.bit_field_true ? "true" : "false" %>` and `<%= @room.bit_field_false ? "true" : "false" %>`, they both yield `true`
- When I show them as strings they show as empty strings

How to I get their respective values? Do the binary values mean anything?

The end goal is to show them in a checkbox, and I have something like:

```
<% form_for(@room) do |room_f| %>
  <%= check_box_tag :room_bit_field_false %><br/>
  <%= check_box_tag :room_bit_field_true %><br/>
<% end %>
```

but it always shows as unchecked. I'm not certain this is how to create checkboxes for this set up, so this could be wrong as well, but regardless I want to know how to extract the bit values in code.

For reference, I'm using Ruby on Rails 2.3.2, with the `mysql` adapter and mysql `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.10, for osx10.6 (i386)`.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered something a lot simpler than `bitfields` as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/11394467/111884 (which I couldn't get working - maybe it was rails 2 or something) - the method `getbyte`.

You can get the first bit with:

```
bit_field_false.getbyte(0)  # Returns `0`
bit_field_true.getbyte(0)   # Returns `1`
```

Also found that you can do this:

```
bit_field_false == "\0"  # Returns `true`
bit_field_false == "\1"  # Returns `false`

bit_field_true == "\0"   # Returns `false`
bit_field_true == "\1"   # Returns `true`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using the bit field to store boolean values I'd suggest you're making your life a lot harder than it needs to be.

Use boolean fields here and it'll all be far simpler. Working hard like this is usually an indicator that you're working against Rails, not with it.

... having said that, I've worked with bit fields and Redis a bit (for storing permissions). If you want to do it in ActiveRecord, a plugin like https://github.com/grosser/bitfields seems like a much nicer way to do it.

Comment: I'm working with an existing database, and the rails site is more of a wrapper around the data, which is generated elsewhere. So it would be easier to get the bit datatype working, than modify the database. Thanks for the tip on bitfields plugin - I'll give it a go.

Comment: When you said 'boolean' in the 2nd paragraph, I think you meant an alternative, such as an integer.  If I remember correctly, unless you're piling up bitfields into larger quantities (some quantity of 8, because of how they get stored) you don't really get any space savings.  Unless you have a serious space constraint, the native integer speed, plus the ease of dealing with Rails, would make an alternative a better choice.